# Master-Master replication MariaDB failover resync

Tags: mariadb, master-master-replication

I'm working on a project to replicate two sites running MariaDB 5.5 version. Replication works flawless until a host restarts, losing connection still works after reconnecting. When the node restarts if i manually enter the new master status to both servers they resume and replicate all data which were non replicated. Is there a way to auto-resume and resync the replication whenever something like this happens? Nodes are in a production environment so downtime with no recovery isn't allowed. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to upgrade to MariaDB 10.0 and use [Global Transaction IDs](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/gtid/). Replication isn't crash safe in 5.5, so you might encounter issues such as the one you've described above.